# Product listing page layer navigation by color ,size etc

Tags: magento-1.9, filter

I am using magento CE 1.9.2.2.

First issue is when i am setting the category `Is anchor` to `yes` and then I am clicking on front end it show processing error. If is anchor set to `no` then front categories work fine.

Second i want to show the filter on product listing page by `color` ,`size` issue is i want to when i click on `size` it show all sizes in dropdown from where i select same is the color.

when category `is anchor` is `yes` clicking on category on front end getting this error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:74:"Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Text_List::(Array([0] => currency) )";
i:1;s:1571:"#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('', Array) 
    #1 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->('currency') 
    #2 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
    #3 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(2
```

Comment: when category is anchor is yes clicking on category on front end getting this error.  

[code]
a:5:{i:0;s:74:"Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Text_List::(Array([0] => currency)
)";i:1;s:1571:"#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->('currency')
#2 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(2
[/code]

Comment: Hi Pearl and welcome to MageOverflow. Please edit your question if you have to add anything. Then it is readable. Use formatting to make it even better readable. And only post ONE question in one QUESTION, not two. Just open another one. If they are linked, link them :-)

Comment: Please edit the question and add the rest of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full error

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:74:"Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Text_List::(Array
(
    [0] => currency
)
)";i:1;s:1571:"#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->('currency')
#2 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\local\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\local\ARW\Filter\controllers\Catalog\CategoryController.php(41): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\local\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): ARW_Filter_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#8 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#9 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 G:\xampp\htdocs\dev2\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:21:"/dev2/index.php/women";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/dev2/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Comment: Please donot put  this in an answer